# How do I connect dual monitors to my laptop?

Tags: multiple-monitors, hdmi, vga, dvi, usb-c

Trying to connect two monitors to my laptop. These are the devices I am using:

Laptop : ThinkBook 15 G3 ACL Laptop
Monitor 1: Dell LCD monitor
Monitor 2: Sansui lcd tv

My think book does not have a vga or dvi port.
The Dell has DVI and VGA port
Sansui has VGA port with non pc related ports as it is a tv.

I have a DVI to hdmi cord that works to connect the Dell to my laptop.

My question is can I connect the Sansui to the Dell using VGA cord? Or is purchasing a vga to hdmi/usb c the only option?

Comment: No, you can't connect 2 monitors together (at best you can daisy-chain monitors with compatible DisplayPorts). An adapter is, again, the only option.

Answer (score 2):

HDMI does not support daisy chaining multiple displays off a single connection.

According to your laptops spec sheet, it can support at most 3 external displays, across the single HDMI port and two USB-C ports.

Since you are already using the HDMI port with your Monitor, your only option to add an additional display is to buy a USB-3 display adapter for your TV.

https://psref.lenovo.com/syspool/Sys/PDF/ThinkBook/ThinkBook_15_G3_ACL/ThinkBook_15_G3_ACL_Spec.pdf